# Better way of creating generic RxJS function that loops over paginated data?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, pagination

I've adapted the example in Da Feng's article, [RXJS Fetch All Paginated Data](https://huantao.medium.com/rxjs-fetch-all-paginated-data-96500b73c120), to retrieve all records from an API response that uses the `nextToken` field to indicate that the response is paginated and that there are further pages of data to return. I expect to be following this pattern in several places, so I'd like to turn this into a generic function, `recursivelyFetchAll`, that takes the name of the field containing the returned data as a parameter. The API response will have different fields containing the returned data for different endpoints, e.g. the `/accounts` endpoint returns `{ accounts: AccountRecord[], nextToken?: string }` but the `/resources` endpoint returns `{ resources: ResourceRecord[], nextToken?: string }`.

I've got a draft of the generic version of the function, but I don't like how `T` and `U` are two separate types. Is there a way to reduce this to a single generic type parameter? And is there a better way of writing the generic type parameter? It looks a little awkward.

```
const recursivelyFetchAll = <
  T extends { [key: string]: U[] | string | undefined, nextToken?: string },
  U
>(
  request$: (nextToken?: string) => Observable<T>,
  key: keyof T
): Observable<U[]> =>
  request$().pipe(
    expand((response) => {
      const { nextToken } = response;
      if (nextToken) {
        return request$(nextToken);
      } else {
        return EMPTY;
      }
    }),
    reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr[key] as U[]), [] as U[])
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but this is a quick guess toward something that might work.

```js
type Nextable = {
  nextToken?: string
}

type Fetch<T> = {
  [key: string]: T[]
}

type FetchNextable<T> = Nextable & Fetch<T>;

function recursivelyFetchAll<T>(
  request: (nextToken?: string) => Observable<FetchNextable<T>>,
  key: keyof FetchNextable<T>
): Observable<T[]> {
  return request().pipe(
    expand(({ nextToken }) => nextToken ? request(nextToken) : EMPTY),
    reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr[key]), [] as T[])
  );
}
```

Comment: Good thinking, but TS complains about the index signature: `Property 'nextToken' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ComplianceResourceRecord[]'.ts(2345)`

Comment: Called as `recursivelyFetchAll<Resource>(...)`

Comment: @KitPeters Ah, maybe you cannot use intersection over an indexed signature. Bummer. You can switch it to a type union. You lose some type safety (It won't enforce that nextToken is a string instead of an array) but retain most of the generic nature. There might be some other way, just not sure to be honest.